# Não consigo subir o meu projeto no repositório do GitHub

Tags: git, github

Boa tarde. Fiz um curso sobre o Git e estou seguindo os passos para inserir um projeto em um repositório no GitHub. Quando executo o comando "git push origin master" no Git Bash, o programa redireciona para outra janela solicitando o login no Github. Executo o login no Github, porém aparece uma janela solicitando autorização do Git Credential Manager. O botão de autorização está desabilitado. Como devo proceder?
Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Tente colocar uma imagem do problema fica mais fácil pra galera aqui do Stack overflow

Comment: Você está dando um push para um repositório que você tem autorização de envio? Experimente refazer os passos de criar as chaves e não coloque senha junto com a chave, para diminuir estes problemas iniciais.

Comment: Estou dando um push para um repositório, porém sou redirecionada para uma página pedindo autorização do Git Credential Manager, mas o botão do autorizar está desabilitado. Estou usando o sistema operacional Windows e essa janela é aberta pelo Internet Explorer. As credenciais de nome e e-mail estão configuradas.

Answer (score -3):

Eu estava com esse erro no Microsoft Edge, mas quando copiei o link dele e colei no Chrome, consegui autorizar e prosseguir.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).